# PDO pass by reference notice?

Tags: php, pdo, pass-by-reference

This:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT thing FROM table WHERE color = :color");
$stmt->bindParam(':color', $someClass->getColor());
$stmt->execute();
```

yields this:

> **Runtime notice** 
>  Only variables should be passed by
>   reference

though it still executes.

This:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT thing FROM table WHERE color = :color");
$tempColor = $someClass->getColor();
$stmt->bindParam(':color',$tempColor);
$stmt->execute();
```

runs without complaint.

I don't understand the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter of bindParam is a variable [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). Since a function return cannot be referenced, it fails to strictly meet the needs of the bindParam parameter (PHP will work with you though and will only issue a warning here).

To get a better idea, here's and example: this code will produce the same results as your second example:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT thing FROM table WHERE color = :color");
$tempColor = NULL; // assigned here
$stmt->bindParam(':color',$tempColor);
$tempColor = $someClass->getColor(); // but reassigned here
$stmt->execute();
```

That won't be possible with a function return.

Answer (score 9):

The description of `PDOStatement::bindParam()` states that it binds a PHP *variable* to a quesitonmark or named placeholder. Since you are trying to pass a class's method (even though that method does return a value) it is still not a variable name, hence the warning. You might want to look at `PDOStatement::bindValue()` to future-proof your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid assigning the value to a variable, you might be better off trying:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT thing FROM table WHERE color = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($someClass->getColor()));
```

As others have mentioned, the error is caused because [PDO::statement->bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) expects param 2 to be a variable passed by reference.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to bind a value instead of a reference, you can use the [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) and then you code would look something like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT thing FROM table WHERE color = :color");
$stmt->bindValue('color', $someObject->getColor());
$stmt->execute();
```