# Hash Password in PDO Error/Notice

Tags: php, pdo, bindparam

If I run this I get the following error:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /var/www/interface/register.php on line 11
>       Success

I dont know how to fix that. It's still successful and the data is hashed in the database, but I don't want this notice.

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));


    if ($stmt->execute()) :
        die('Success');
    else:
        die('Fail');
    endif;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead. Or just use [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT) inside [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), because [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) returns a string, do:

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
```

If you wish to leave the values there use [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php):

```
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

because it allows varibles by reference.

### Explanation:

**bindParam** expects a variable or const it can't be a primitive type such as a string or an int, ..., explicitly (ex: "some_hardcoded_string") neither can it be a function that returns one of this types.

**bindValue** can receive references and primitive types as an argument.

---

Examples for both:

```
$query->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->bindValue(':pass', sha1($password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

SHA1 is returns a value, it could be a number 12345 (let's say for the sake of the example)

```
$query->bindValue(':pass', 12345, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

or a string.

```
$query->bindValue(':pass', 'hashed_password', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

---

retated questions:

- [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in m_auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243199/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-in-m-auth)
- [PDO pass by reference notice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770850/pdo-pass-by-reference-notice)
- [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765099/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)